# Eslint | How to make eslint to remove spaces in brackets

Tags: eslint

How to make eslint to remove spaces in brackets? I've added this rule

```
"space-in-brackets": ["error", "always"],
```

But it just shows me errors ;(

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
'computed-property-spacing': ["error", "never"],
```